# Retrieve value from html and print to controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

From the above title, is there any way to get the value from the html page?
Currently, i use thymleaf template and want to get the value from th:value = "*{projectName}", th:text="*{projectTask}" and th:value="*{projectStatus}"

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 70px">
    <h2>Status Project</h2>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/updateProject/__${projectId}__}"  method="post"
          id="addProject">
        <div>
            <label for="usr">Project Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" th:value="*{projectName}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px">
            <label for="comment">ITO Task:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" th:text="*{projectTask}"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-left: 0px; ">
            <label for="usr">Status:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" th:value="*{projectStatus}">
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="padding-top: 20px;right: 205px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : 
Accept all the parameters separately something like below code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String create(@RequestParam("projectName") String projectName,@RequestParam("projectTask") String projectTask,,@RequestParam("projectStatus") String projectStatus, BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
*//code goes here*
}
```

Solution 2 : 
Accept as a pojo object like below code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String create(@Valid Project project, BindingResult bindingResult,Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
*//code goes here*
}
```

NOTE: Create a pojo class which includes these fields to refer Solution 2.